# Get the metatable for foreign key

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm working on a method that received an EF MetaTable object and I need to return a list of MetaTable objects for all the related tables. This means both the child tables that have a foreign key to this one and the tables that the foreign keys of this table are pointing to. The problem? I only have an object of type [MetaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.metatable(v=vs.110).aspx).
So, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...

```
var parents = table.Columns.OfType<MetaForeignKeyColumn>().Select(s => s.ParentTable).Distinct();
var children = table.Columns.OfType<MetaChildrenColumn>().Select(s => s.ChildTable).Distinct();
```

Wasn't too difficult once you realise this typecast trick.